# send fist form1 textbox from second opened form2

Tags: vb.net

i tried some codes but i didnt worked my want

how can i send first form's textbox from form2

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim F As New Form2
         
        F.Show()
    End Sub
```

second forms code

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
Dim FRM As New Form1
        FRM.Datagridview1.Rows.Add()
        FRM.Datagridview1.rows(0).cells(0).value=1 
End Sub
```

i press button1 but nothing happens

Comment: You are trying to add a row to a new declared Object (that is FRM = Form1). 
Without a .Show obviously your button does nothing (THAT IS VISIBLE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, in the second form code, you **create** a new form1.

In vb.net you can try this in your second form : (without creating a new form1)

```
[first_form_name].Datagridview1.rows(0).cells(0).value=1
```

Comment: Ok thanks ,
İ did my project again  with my home pc then the problem solved